# Is there a way to make the game announce whenever I advance in an achievement?

Tags: diablo-iii

There are games that announce to the player once they advance in an achievement. Is there a way to do the same with Diablo. So that every time I open another chest/kill a new unique enemy the game will announce to me that I've advanced toward getting the challenge and how much I have left?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, no announcements for advancing in an achievement exist besides the completion announcement. However, to track your progress you can still open the achievement menu and have a look on the progress bars there.

Comment: One thing worth noting, is that the achievements screen in itself does not appear to upgrade 'partial progress' very frequently, so you can end up in the situation where you need to listen to kill 100 enemies from long range or slow down projectiles, and the counters don't update in real time but you still get the achievement at the right time.

Comment: @ickleislands: I didn't observe a delay yet, do you have any source/proof? I just watched the achievement progress for "Big Trouble in a Talking Barrel" and it was accurate and updated as soon as progress was made.

Comment: no source or proof, I have experienced this myself while playing. A good one to check yourself to see if you have this problem would be 'gold picked up'. I had a quick google as I had seen this mentioned on the official D3 forums a few weeks back but didn't find a link.

Comment: one other thing, the Shen achievement did seem to update in real time (i was in the process of using that as my example in my original comment hence the badly edited 'where you need to listen to kill' but remembered that this one did work). The ones I've noticed it on are gold picked up, the achievement for breaking ashes, killing X enemies without reaching max spirit (spirited away), etc

Comment: [This thread](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73454/why-doesnt-blowin-in-the-winds-count-update) has an instance of an achievement not updating.